# Difficulty with MFC template project in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, richedit

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to experiment with MFC.

I have created a template MFC project by following the wizard. I chose a dialog based app, and unchecked other options like ActiveX controls.

After making no code changes, I hit F5, and the app runs.

Then, using the form designer, I drag a rich edit control from the toolbox onto the app. I hit F5 again, and the app compiles but exits with error code 0 instantly.

Why could this be happening? What am I doing wrong?

This is the output when the RichEdit is included:

```
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\odpmfc2\Debug\odpmfc2.exe', Symbols loaded.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc100ud.dll', Symbols loaded.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16385_none_ebf82fc36c758ad5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc100enu.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
The program '[7420] odpmfc2.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

It is a bit suspicious that all these load errors are occurring. But if something is going wrong, why is it exiting with error code 0?

Here is the output from a successful run. The load failures still occur:

```
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\odpmfc2\Debug\odpmfc2.exe', Symbols loaded.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc100ud.dll', Symbols loaded.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16385_none_ebf82fc36c758ad5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc100enu.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'odpmfc2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[7956] odpmfc2.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**UPDATE** I removed the RichEdit, and added these other controls, and it works fine:

- MFC VSListBox Control
- List Control
- MFC Link Control
- Network Address Control

**Tangent**: Why is RichEdit2 the only RichEdit available in the form builder? (I'm using VS 2010 on Windows 7)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I needed to add this call:

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("riched20.dll"));
```

As noted on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787877(v=VS.85).aspx):

> In Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and
>   later, it is possible to add a rich
>   edit control into a dialog template by
>   dragging the control from the toolbox.
>   However, doing this in the dialog
>   editor does not ensure that the
>   required library will be loaded before
>   the control is created. It is
>   necessary to call the LoadLibrary
>   function to load Riched32.dll,
>   Riched20.dll, or Msftedit.dll before
>   the dialog is created.

Comment: In MFC, you can also just call AfxInitRichEdit2().